# JS redirect not loading static content

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to redirecting page when someone clicks an image, I'm using javascript do do this

```
    function showChampionDetails(champion){
    window.location.href = "/champions/#" + normalizeChampionName(champion);
}
```

The url is working but for some reason all static resources are charging from

localhost/champions instead of its normal way localhost/js/...etc
[image]

Any ideas why could this happen? thanks.

Comment: have you referenced them relatively? change the paths to start with a slash, like `<script src="/js/file.js">`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the browser is treating your request as being served from the `champions` "folder" (conceptually) and you are probably referencing your JS files using relative URLs.

The solution: use root-relative URLs:

```
<script src="/libraries/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid, i was redirecting it using /champions/#name and i twas /champions#name. Hope this helps someone.